# What is the point of this (user)?

Tags: discussion, users

I just [reviewed a suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6762008). The suggested edit was so pointless that I decided to look at the users profile out of curiosity. What is wrong with this guy? He is a member for 5 month now and it seems he didn't contribute *anything* until now. But today he decided to log in to edit a post just to add "xoxox" at the end of it?

Sorry, but this doesn't compute...

Can there be any reasoning that might explain such a behavior?
What should I as a reviewer do in such a case? Should I report/flag him for moderator attention? Should I somehow try to contact him to ask if he is alright (*no* joke here)?

Or should I better just accept that there are certain things in life one better doesn't care about, doesn't question, and doesn't talk about.

Comment: Go ask him...;)

Comment: @Martijn I think, Balder is asking about the global context here, not a single person (this specific user).

Comment: Probably 'xoxox' is first part of some encrypted message. We should patiently wait for another parts.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just review the content on its own merits. The edit appears to be an attempt at trolling, but simply rejecting these will lead to an edit ban if it happens often enough.

If you do see a pattern of trolling behaviour, just flag one of the posts for moderator attention, use *Other* and explain that the user is engaging in disruptive behaviour. They'll take it from there.

In general, please don't drag specific user behaviour to Meta. Normal users cannot handle cases of abuse, that should be left to the moderators. We certainly won't be any help in explaining why an account suddenly switched from a dormant state to making pointless edits.